# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character [...]

Tags: python, unicode

I have read the [HOWTO on Unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) from the official docs and a full, very detailed [article](http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode) as well. Still I don't get it why it throws me this error.

Here is what I attempt: I open an XML file that contains chars out of ASCII range (but inside allowed XML range). I do that with `cfg = codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8, mode='r')` which runs fine. Looking at the string with `repr()` also shows me a unicode string.

Now I go ahead and read that with `parseString(cfg.read().encode('utf-8')`. Of course, my XML file starts with this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Although I suppose it is not relevant, I also defined utf-8 for my python script, but since I am not writing unicode characters directly in it, this should not apply here. Same for the following line: `from __future__ import unicode_literals` which also is right at the beginning.

Next thing I pass the generated Object to my own class where I read tags into variables like this: `xmldata.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0].firstChild.data` and assign it to a variable in my class.

Now what perfectly works are those commands (obj is an instance of the class):

```
for element in obj:
    print element
```

And this command does work as well:

```
print obj.__repr__()
```

I defined `__iter__()` to just yield every variable while `__repr__()` uses the typical printf stuff: `"%s" % self.varname`

Both commands print perfectly and can output the unicode character.
What does not work is this:

```
print obj
```

And now I am stuck because this throws the dreaded

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 47:
```

So what am I missing? What am I doing wrong? I am looking for a general solution, I always want to handle strings as unicode, just to avoid any possible errors and write a compatible program.

Edit: I also defined this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.__repr__()
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.__repr__()
```

From documentation I got that this

Comment: `print obj` will use the object's `__str__`, not `__repr__`.

Comment: What is your default encoding? I mean *sys.getdefaultencoding()*

Comment: @BrenBarn : __str__ is implemented as return __repr__()

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha: it is ascii according to the function

Comment: I would really recommend taking a look at this talk at Pycon 2012 Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: @root thank you very much. Great talk, even some news for me. It did lead me closer to solving my problem (I understood it better). See my own answer to what finally solved it.

Comment: My default is ascii.  I thought Python defaulted to utf-8?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was (I am not sure why) that if you called either `__str__()` or `__repr__()` directly it would be hapyp to handle it well, but printing it directly (as in: `print obj`) does not work (although it should only just call `__str__()` itself).

The final help came from this [article](http://wiki.python.de/Von%20Umlauten,%20Unicode%20und%20Encodings). I already got to the step where I got it to print to the console (but a wrong letter) when I used utf-8 encoding. Finally solved it to be perfectly correct by defining this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.__repr__().encode(stdout.encoding)
```

Now the only open question that remains is: Why do `print obj.__str__()` and `print obj` differently with this? It does make no sense to me. And yes, to stress that again: Calling the former or `__repr__()` DID work. And still does with the explicit encoding.

Comment: The help article is no longer available